# Update query does not return any values

Tags: ms-access

When I try to create a simple update query with Subtraction or anything else in the same table, it doesn't return me any value, could it be something to do with formating?

This is SQL code: `UPDATE Sales SET Sales.GrossProfit = [SubTot]-[Cost];`

It doesn't return any value.

I have copied syntax from different databases (from colleagues) where the same type of query worked. Could it be something to do with my general Access settings?

`UPDATE Sales SET Sales.GrossProfit = [SubTot]-[Cost];`

I expect the query to update the GrossProfit column with the calculation `"SubTot - Cost"`

Comment: Can you please give us an example of the data you're working with? Including what results you are getting when you try?

Comment: Values in SubTot and Cost are Number values for example: 7.85 and 16.90 When I subtract them in a select query it works fine, but as soon as it is an update query it returns me a column without any values in it.

Comment: Why are you trying to store calculated data in a table? Any specific reason for this as normally you shouldn't.

Comment: Update query won't show a value in design view. Is the table updated when you run the query? I also ask - why save? Is aggregate data?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, an UPDATE query does not "return" any columns.  It only changes data in existing rows, but by itself does not return those changes back to you.  (It is more accurately called an Update *statement* since it does not return data.)

For instance, if you were to execute the UPDATE statement in VBA code, you would *not* get a RecordSet of columns like with a SELECT query.  To get the results *after* executing the UPDATE statement would require that you execute a separate SELECT query.

However, I assume that you are **viewing the Update query in the Access query designer**.  **Correct?**

In that case, when you click on the View button (Datasheet View), Access tries to be smart & useful about the UPDATE and *converts it temporarily* into a SELECT query so that you can visualize the **existing data** in the columns.  **The Datasheet View does not actually run the UPDATE statement, nor does it show a preview of what will happen when you do run it.**

While in **Design View** or **SQL View** for an Update query (or for Delete, Make Table, and Append queries), there is a **Run button** with a red exclamation point (on the Design ribbon/toolbar).  Clicking that button will actually execute the query that changes the table values.  Although it will not show you results row by row, you should get a pop-up telling you how many rows were changed due to the statement.  (You may also get confirmation prompts that the statement is about to change data in the table.)

[image: Run button for Access Update query]